# Проблема с ajax или с денвером?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Есть страница .php, для нее есть .js, в котором есть ассоциативный массив, для передачи на другую стр .php. Дело в том, что он формирует строку и вроде как должен отправлять на другую стр, но `$_POST` - пустой, не пойму в чем дело

Есть вот такой код:

```js
$("form").submit(function () {
        switch(this.id) {
            case "table-form":
                var $reserveName=$('#reserveName').val();
                var $telephone=$('#telephone').val();
                var $email=$('#email').val();
                var $promo=$('#promo').val();

                var dataTable = {
                    reserveName:  $reserveName,
                    telephone: $telephone,
                    email: $email,
                    promo: $promo 
                };
                alert("OK");
                post("/baze.php",dataTable);

                return false;
                break;
    }
}
```

И вот такой вот обработчик

```js
function post(url,data){
    var stringed = JSON.stringify(data);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: {dataTab: stringed }
    });

}
```

и вот такой php:

```php
print_r($_POST['dataTab']);
$udxarr = json_decode(str_replace('\\', '', $_POST['dataTab']));
$udxarr2 = json_decode($_POST['dataTab']);
```

если сделать так:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/baze.php',
            data: {dataTab: stringed }

          });
```

то приходят поля не на baze.php,а на ту же страницу, ничего не понимаю

Comment: Зачем вы слеши-то убираете? Если они там есть, то обратно json уже не распарсится.

Comment: скопировал откуда-то, по-этому и так и так сделал, но один фиг не работает

Comment: Что выдает `print_r($_REQUEST)`? Страница перезагружается?

Comment: `print_r($_REQUEST)` добавил вроде ничего не меняется, пишет `NULL`

Comment: **JSON.stringify** - не нужно делать в Вашем случае

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем, видимо я не понимаю каких то простых вещей, потому что все наверное работает, просто почему-то не отображается в `var_export($_POST)`
Сделал так и все хорошо работает, только не видно, все пустое, даже `echo`

```
function post(url,data){

    jQuery.post(url, data)      

};
```

Answer (score -1):

$.ajax сам переводит данные в json и на сервере $_POST и $_GET также автоматом декодируются из json в массив, так что попробуйте убрать

> JSON.stringify(data);

Comment: откуда информация что `$_GET` и `$_POST` автоматом декодируются из JSON?

Comment: и так тоже пробовал, не работает, делаю `success: function(){
    alert('Load was performed.');}
    error:function(){
    alert('ERROR');}` - перезагружает страницу и добавляет знак вопроса в ссылку